# How to save Mongoose data through express and react correctly?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

NextJS Code:

```
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <form action="http://localhost:2000/register" method="post">
        <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="first" name="first" />
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="last" name="last" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Express Code:

```
router.post('/register', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const user = await User.create({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
    });
    return res.status(200).json(user);
});
```

The schema for that is:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
});

export const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

When I enter name + email, its only saving the _id, nothing else, why?

Comment: Is there a value in the `req.body.name` and email?

Comment: yea it is, there is something wrong with the frontend tho